# Scroll content size not getting set.Horizontal scroll not needed

Tags: ios

I have designed the  view in xib using auto layout and programmatically am trying to set the content size of scrollview.Horizontal scroll is happening on load which am not expecting.On orientation of device  the scroll size is set properly but on load it is not working and am able to scroll horizontally .How to avoid this?

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{

 scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scroll.frame.size.width, attBtn.frame.origin.y+attBtn.frame.size.height+40);//attBtn added programmatically

}
```

Comment: You can uncheck horizontal scroll bar's property from IB.

Comment: Are you setting content size for scroll view same as your screenbounds width. Also there can be issue with changing content size, try to execute set content size code with delay in view did load, because scroll view takes time to load and layout itself.